# How to fetch which value is selected in Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to fetch the value for which option is selected in the `select_layer`. I think passing some functions to `onChange` will work, but I cannot figure out how.

```
var identifier_dropdown = "<select class='form-select' id='select_layer'>"+
"<option selected>Open this select menu</option>"
for(let i=0;i<checkedLayers ;i++) {
identifier_dropdown += "<option value='"+(i)+"' >"+checkedLayersTitles[i]+"</option>"
}
identifier_dropdown += "</select>"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], esp. [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Resources: [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/select/), [examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=react+bootstrap+select+example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `eventListener` :

```
let mySelect = document.querySelector('#select_layer');
mySelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let selectedValue = mySelect.value;
    // do some stuff here
});
```